# Excess space on the right

Tags: iphone, css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
body {
  background: #474747 url(bg.png);
}
h1 a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 40px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  letter-spacing: -5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  text-shadow: 0px 5px 8px #2a2a2a;
}
h2 {
  font: 30px Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #222;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
}
div#mobile pre {
  width: 275px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #222;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #555;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #171717;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}
```

This is what I have so far on an iPhone-optimized version of my site. But when viewed from an iPhone/iPod touch, it looks well, except that there is excess space on the right. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hard to tell.  Could it be that the `bg.png` is too small for the device width?

Comment: Can you supply a live link or put up an example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://switch.tk/ <- view it on a Desktop and then on an iPhone/iPOd Touch. And no, the bg.png is a perfect size as it fit perfectly before I added the pre {}.

Comment: Adding non-answers to "bump" your question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6104754/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have some tabs or spaces after your "labels". You should also have the text in label-elements.

What you might have:

```
<pre> <form method="post" action="/index.php">Enter a URL<br />(WITH THE http://):               <br /><input type="text" name="url"> 
<br />Want a custom tag?                    <br /><input type="text" name="custom"> 
</form> 
No URL was entered.</pre>
```

What you should have:

```
<form method="post" action="/index.php">
  <label for="url">
    Enter a URL (WITH THE http://):
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="url"> 
  <label for="custom">
    Want a custom tag?
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="custom"> 
</form> 
<p>No URL was entered.</p>
```

Then you need to style it to make it look like before. Remember the pre-element is usually used to output code.